# How to wait thread start point until method done

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio

There's thread order method like `thread.join()`

But how to wait thread start point until not thread method done

I made button click listener. In there `takePicture` function need to start and finish  before start `Thread`.

But when I debug, `takePicture` and `Thread` start almost simultaneously.

How can I prevent this?

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        takePicture();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                send();
            }
        }).start();
    }
});
```

++++++

make `takePicture` to thread and do `join()` before starting below thread not working

this also below thread done first...

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    takePicture();
                }
            });
            thread1.start();
            thread1.join();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("point", "3");
                    send(image_byte);
                }
            }).start();
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking for. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @codeflush.dev ```new Thread``` start when ```takePicture``` is Done.

Comment: Your first code snippet does that

Comment: @codeflush.dev No, I test already. I attach ```Log.d``` for checking who first calling. ```new Thread``` always called first than ```takePicture```.